# User: XYZ does not have permission='SEND' on address

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am able to authenticate via web console as well as via the `bin/artemis producer` command with credentials from my LDAP server. When I use the same credentials with `mosquitto_pub` to the same topic the log says

```
User: $username does not have permission='SEND' on address $address"
```

I've verified the resolved roles in the logs as well - they are the same for `mosquitto_pub` as for `artemis producer`. In my case they resolve a `producer` role which has `admin` privileges.

Is there any difference in authorization depending on the protocols? As it seems the authorization works for the CORE protocol and also for AMQP (I've tested both via `artemis producer`).

Unfortunately I cannot cross-check that with the `artemis producer --protocol MQTT` - this fails with "protocol MQTT not supported".

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference with authorization between protocols as they're all doing the same thing ultimately. Also, the `producer` command only supports core and AMQP. Lastly, it might help to get everything working as you expect *without* LDAP first (e.g. using the standard properties files for users and roles & standard security-setting entries). [Gall's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gall_(author)#Gall's_law) and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#legacyldapsecuritysettingplugin), the legacy `admin` permission is not mapped to the `send` permission:

> ActiveMQ 5.x only has 3 permission types - `read`, `write`, and `admin`. These permission types are described on their [website](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html). However, as described previously, ActiveMQ Artemis has 9 permission types - `createAddress`, `deleteAddress`, `createDurableQueue`, `deleteDurableQueue`, `createNonDurableQueue`, `deleteNonDurableQueue`, `send`, `consume`, `browse`, and `manage`. Here's how the old types are mapped to the new types:
>
> - `read` - `consume`, `browse`
> - `write` - `send`
> - `admin` - `createAddress`, `deleteAddress`, `createDurableQueue`, `deleteDurableQueue`, `createNonDurableQueue`, `deleteNonDurableQueue`, `manage` (if `mapAdminToManage` is `true`)

Therefore, your `producer` role needs the `write` permission.

It's not clear why the `producer` command is working for other protocols (i.e. core & AMQP), but based on what you've provided I believe this is why it isn't working for MQTT.

Comment: The situation does not occur anymore and seems not reproducible to myself. The only thing I did though was to reset my Artemis broker and to reset the LDAP records completely. Thanks for the hints anyway, maybe I had messed up my roles. I'll accept this answer because it seems to be a legitimate cause.